# Removing the Hashtag From stored value

Tags: javascript, html, input, colors

```
<input type="color" id="color" placeholder="Enter color">
  <div class="select">

const color = document.getElementById("color").value;
```

In short I wanna build a program that lets user input the color, and that the value of the color needs to be sent to another program without the hashtag.

I was wandering is there a way that I remove Hashtag from Const color.
Would be great if I can keep the same const name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change const color, but you can just send:

```
color.replace('#', '')
```

Output would be like 'FFFFFF' if previously it was '#FFFFFF'

or you can use replace to value:

```
const color = document.getElementById("color").value.replace('#', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const colorInput = document.getElementById('color');

colorInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const colorValue = colorInput.value.replace('#', '');
  console.log(colorValue);
});
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color" placeholder="Enter color">
```

a constant cannot be assigned a new value